# ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist. while trying to create a replica set in onrder to use mongoconnector for elastic search

Tags: mongodb

while trying to create a replica set of db i get an error that dbpath /data/db  does not exist.i am currently running mongo in docker as root. 
  version(mongo) 2.6..10.
i start using the service mongodb start command after which the mongo shell appears.log below

root@5936a72e744f:/dbex# mongod --replSet myDevReplSet

2017-07-31T05:13:30.946+0000 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=679 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=5936a72e744f
2017-07-31T05:13:30.947+0000 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.10
2017-07-31T05:13:30.947+0000 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2017-07-31T05:13:30.947+0000 [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-07-31T05:13:30.947+0000 [initandlisten] build info: Linux lgw01-12 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_58
2017-07-31T05:13:30.948+0000 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-07-31T05:13:30.949+0000 [initandlisten] options: { replication: { replSet: "myDevReplSet" } }
2017-07-31T05:13:30.950+0000 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296

---

ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo

---

, terminating

Comment: So what is not descriptive about the error? There is actually even a link to documentation that comes with it, so how more descriptive does it need to get?

Comment: True.but in the documentation it says how to change default path of data.i am able to start mongo shell just fine.i do not get a connection error when i type mongo.....but when i create a replication set it throws error that data path does not exist.

Comment: Because you are "starting a new instance". And unlike the one that is already running it has no such configuration that tells it where to create it's data files or any other options. Perhaps you actually should have read the manual before you started putting the bike together. [Deploy a Replica Set for Testing and Development](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-for-testing/)

Comment: Of course if all you really wanted to do was "enable a replica set" on your existsing instance so there is an "oplog" that can be followed by a tailable cursor, then you need but add: [`replSetName: myDevReplSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#replication.replSetName) to your existing config, likely at `/etc/mongod.conf`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look into your /etc/mongod.conf you will see

```
storage:
 dbPath: /data/db
```

So create directory /data/db and ensure proper permission.

Comment: in mongodb.conf..the path is...dbpath =/var/lib/mongodb...should i change datapath while setting up replica set.....using below command                                           
 $mongod --port 27017 --dbpath "/var/lib/mongodb" --replSet rs0

Comment: Configuration file is a little different in the latest mongo releases. You said you are trying to create a new replica set, then why don't you try with mongo 3.x.x?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes the data is stored in `var/lib/mongod`.

start a replica set use:

`mongod --port 27017 --dbpath "/var/lib/mongodb" --replSet rs0`

check appropriate location and change `dbpath` location